# file.rename deletes files if filename format is <0-9>.R

Tags: r, rlang

**Description**

This issue appears to apply to vectorised and loop approaches to renaming several files. Vectorised approach used in reprex below. The bug only seems to present when filenames do not contain meaningful or alphanumeric strings.

**Summary**

Existing files prior to file.rename:
"1.R" "2.R" "3.R" "4.R" "5.R".
Existing files following file.rename:
"6.R".
Expected output:
"2.R" "3.R" "4.R" "5.R" "6.R"

**Reprex**

```
library(stringr)
# how many files to create
req_nos <- c(1:5)
# create file names
req_names <- paste(req_nos, "R", sep = ".")
# create the files
invisible(file.create(req_names))
# adjust the numbering plus 1
new_nos <- as.character(req_nos + 1)
# create new names with the new numbering
new_names <- str_replace(req_names, "^[0-9]*", new_nos)
# file.rename loses the files up to the largest value of new_nos
file.rename(from = req_names, to = new_names)
```

**devtools::session_info**

```
─ Session info 
***
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
 os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7      
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2021-03-20                  

─ Packages 
***
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 audio         0.1-7   2020-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 beepr         1.3     2018-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cli           2.3.1   2021-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
 crayon        1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 log4r         0.3.2   2020-01-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgbuild      1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 processx      3.4.5   2020-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ps            1.5.0   2020-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 R6            2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rlang         0.4.10  2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 testthat      3.0.2   2021-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tinytex       0.23    2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 withr         2.4.1   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 xfun          0.21    2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in @CALUM Polwart 's suggestion, reordering the sequence of files to write resolves the issue.
The initial reprex issue was renaming 1.R to 2.R to 3.R and so on.

**Solution**

```
library(stringr)
# how many files to create: REVERSE the sequence
req_nos <- order(-c(1:5))
# create file names
req_names <- paste(req_nos, "R", sep = ".")
# create the files
invisible(file.create(req_names))
# adjust the numbering plus 1
new_nos <- as.character(req_nos + 1)
# create new names with the new numbering
new_names <- str_replace(req_names, "^[0-9]*", new_nos)
# file.rename loses the files up to the largest value of new_nos
file.rename(from = req_names, to = new_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 6.R actually the content of 1.R?

I think you are seeing 1.R renamed to 2.R and over-writing 2.R in the process. The new 2.R to 3.R etc.

```
file.rename(from = req_names, to = new_names, overwrite = F)
```

The above should prevent them being accidentally re-written, but would result in error/warning

If you reverse the order of your rename *in this case* it will prevent an issue

Alternatively rename them to an intermediary

1.R -> 2.R-tmp
2.R -> 3.R-tmp
Etc

Then

2.R-tmp -> 2.R

Comment: that's interesting, I don't have an overwrite argument to `file.rename()` so I edited my question with session info. 

Overwriting is required for my puposes and trying to avoid intemediaries, however my current workaround introduces random hash sequences if files found have the <0-9>.R format.

Could you clarify what you mean by reversing the order of file.rename?

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure over-writing is not required for your purpose! I'm also not convinced it's only a 0-9 issue, it's just that the order is easy to predict in 0-9 and so becomes visible. Are you certain it doesn't happen with a-z?  Reordering... You current name 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc. If you named 5 to 6 and then 4 to 5 you wouldn't have the issue. But that's in the example. Not sure if that works in your use case.

Comment: req_names <- paste(req_nos[order(-req_nos)], "R", sep = ".") Would change the order